# Django isn't recognizing crispy forms

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-crispy-forms

my pip is showing that crispy forms is installed but for some reason when I run manage.py it's saying that it doesn't exist. Here is some history from my terminal that I annotated over for clarity.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-126 bd_website]$ pip list

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Package                      Version
---------------------------- --------
(elements ommitted for brevity...)
Django                       1.11.29
django-crispy-forms          1.9.0 <<Crispy forms is installed, right?
(elements ommitted for brevity...)

[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-126 bd_website]$ pip install django-crispy-forms

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: django-crispy-forms in /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.9.0)

[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-126 bd_website]$ python --version

Python 3.6.11 <<Version is compatible with Django

[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-126 bd_website]$ python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms' <<Apparently not.
```

Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: As you can see `pip` uses the outdated Python 2 and `python` is Python 3.6. This is somehow messed up and you installed the library in the Python 2 environment where Python 3.6 can't see it. Maybe `pip3` uses the correct version.

Comment: Gotcha. I ended up having to specify Python 3.6 pip by using python -m pip install django-crispy-forms. As you implied, it wasn't installed for python 3.6. Thanks for the help. What happened was this machine had Python 2.7 on it originally, and I installed 3.6 on top of it but pip remained configured for 2.7.